# oracle SQL - ORA-009007 Missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this sql

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENTS
(
patientID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
healthInsID NUMBER,
fname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
minit       VARCHAR(15),
lname       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
gender      CHAR(2),
email       VARCHAR(40),
street      VARCHAR(40),
postalCode  NUMBER,
city        VARCHAR(20),
country     VARCHAR(20),

PRIMARY KEY  (patientID),
FOREIGN KEY  (healthInsID) REFERENCES HEALTH_INSURANCES
ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I have no idea why I keep getting this error. I have search a lot but still nothing that can solve it. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You should not use `varchar` in Oracle. Use `varchar2` instead. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1822

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify column from `HEALTH_INSURANCES` table in `FOREIGN KEY` caluse.
You should also remove `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. You can use a `trigger on update` instead of this clause.

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENTS
(
patientID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
healthInsID NUMBER,
fname       VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
minit       VARCHAR(15),
lname       VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
gender      CHAR(2),
email       VARCHAR(40),
street      VARCHAR(40),
postalCode  NUMBER,
city        VARCHAR(20),
country     VARCHAR(20),

PRIMARY KEY  (patientID),
FOREIGN KEY  (healthInsID) REFERENCES HEALTH_INSURANCES (healthInsID)
ON DELETE SET NULL 
);
```

[More information about constraints](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52201)

Comment: @user3118957 I added `You should aslo remove ON UPDATE CASCADE` to my asnwer

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but what if I want to have an update command?

Comment: @user3118957 You should use a trigger.